# How to change the name of a parent folder with php?

Tags: php

I'm developing a web application and want the user to define the name of the URL using an input field.

I know how to find the name of the parent folder but don't know how to overwrite it. I also know how to get the value of the input field so for the sake of keeping it as simple as possible, a hardcoded value would be fine as a solution.

This is how I get the name of the parent folder:

```
$moduleName = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
```

If I echo `$moduleName`, I get the name of the parent folder, which determines the name of the url.

I want to do something like:

```
basename(dirname(__FILE__)) = 'new-name';
```

But I don't know if it is possible to do with php? :)

Comment: Thats not how clean urls works at all. Look at mod_rewrite for url masking. Use some server redirection rules, pass the path to a php script and go from there.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_rename.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try [function.rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

`rename(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/myoldfolder',realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/mynewfolder');`

Credits:

[Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/bdp7ww/rename-folder-in-php)